# how to make load balancer for docker rabbitmq cluster

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I made three docker containers of rabbitmq. 
For applications I forward next ports: 5672, 5673, 5674 from every three containers.
How can I combine this port into one port 5670 ?
And when some application will connect, it will automaticly balance on which node connect tjis application?

Comment: This is better directed at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) as it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Docker swarm does load balancing amongst replicas of a service. You could instantiate a docker swarm of 1 or more hosts and run many replicas of your application there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use haproxy as a load balancer. If you don't want to set you own config, you can use [this image](https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-haproxy#tcp-load-balancing) . Make sure you've set up TCP_PORTS environment variable in you rabbitmq instances and exposed according ports in Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml or when running an instance.